# UITableViewCell subclass with auto layout how to change constraint priority at runtime

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I've got a prototype of a cell inside my storyboard.
Basically the cell is split in two parts:

- a text view
- an image view

The cell is initialized with its values passing an object to cell itself. Inside that method the cell sets its elements to the passed values.
The main idea was to change the cell layout based on the presence of the image or the text. To do so I've over constrained the `UITextView` and the `UIImageView` adding, on one side, two constraints with different priorities. The priority will change according to the passed objects.

[image]
For instance the `UITextView` has two dotted lines, they represent the two constraint with different priorities and different constant values. The first one (reading from LtoR)has a priority of 910 and a constant of 156, the second has a priority of 900 and a constant of 20.

In the storyboard editor if I swap the 2 priorities I obtain visually what I want to achieve.

The cell code:

```
- (void) updateConstraints {
   if (self.postObject.timelinePostText && self.postObject.timelinePostMultimedia) {
       self.imageMinusTextViewConstraint.priority = 900;
       self.imagePlusTextViewConstraint.priority = 910;
       self.textViewMinusImageViewConstraint.priority = 900;
       self.textViewPlusImageViewConstraint.priority = 910;

   }
   else if (self.postObject.timelinePostMultimedia) {
       self.imageMinusTextViewConstraint.priority = 910;
       self.imagePlusTextViewConstraint.priority = 900;
   }
   else if (self.postObject.timelinePostText) {
       self.textViewMinusImageViewConstraint.priority = 910;
       self.textViewPlusImageViewConstraint.priority = 900;
   }

   [super updateConstraints];
}



- (void) configureCellWith: (AFTimelinePostObject*) postObject {
    self.postObject = postObject;
    self.userNameLabel.text = postObject.timelinePostOriginalPoster;
    self.dateLabel.text = [[AFTimelinePostObject dateFormatterInternet] stringFromDate:postObject.timelinePostDateObject];
    self.postTitleLabel.text = postObject.timelinePostTitle;
    self.multimediaMediaType = postObject.timelinePostMultimedia ? [self checkMediaTypeAtPath: postObject.timelinePostMultimedia] : kMediaTypeUnknown;
    if (postObject.timelinePostMultimedia && postObject.timelinePostText) {
        [self.postImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postObject.timelinePostMultimedia] placeholderImage:nil];
        self.postTextView.text = postObject.timelinePostText;
    }
    else if (postObject.timelinePostMultimedia) {
        [self bringSubviewToFront:self.postImageView];
        [self.postImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postObject.timelinePostMultimedia] placeholderImage:nil];
    }
    else if (postObject.timelinePostText) {
        [self bringSubviewToFront:self.postTextView];
        self.postTextView.text = postObject.timelinePostText;
        self.postImageView.image = nil;
    }
    [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [self updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
    [self setNeedsLayout];
    [self layoutIfNeeded];

}
```

Removing a view is not a solution because cells are recycled and I should re-add it if needed, but in this way I guess that I miss the performance advantage related to recycling.
Unfortunately cells remain equally divided into text and image, without changing their frames according to the data passed.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Don't remove views of constraints. Instead, connect the constraints you have setup in xib/storyboard to an outlet in the code, and modify its `constant` value in your `configureCell` method. Don't play with priorities. Change the constant depending on whether there is an image or text.

If your logic only allows **either** text cell **or** image cell, you could set up two different cells with different identifiers and dequeue accordingly. This would simplify you configure logic somewhat.

Also, instead of

```
[self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[self updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
[self setNeedsLayout];
[self layoutIfNeeded];
```

Simply call `[self setNeedsLayout];`

Comment: Thanks Leo, for you suggestions. Actually the production code use different cells for kind of possibility. I don't want to to change the constant, because I think that I will miss the possibility to work only on  the storyboard editor later, yes I can swap the constant values between the two. The point here is that what I want to do is possible, I'm pretty sure about it, but I'm not getting why is not working, or at leat I want to be sure that is not possible.

Comment: @Andrea It seems to me that the reason you still see both the text view and image view is because there is no "fighting" between the constraints, so it takes no priority, because as it is, the cell satisfies the layout constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've extracted a small sample to make things simple.
There where basically two errors:

1. Priorities shouldn't be update in `updateConstraints`, I still trying to find a quite clear answer about the porpoise of this method, but it seems that you should use only if you ADD (probably remove is not considered) constraint
2. I was sending the -`bringSubViewToFront` to the wrong parent, the correct is the `-contentView`

Here is the correct code, thanks @Leo for supporting me.

```
//- (void) updateConstraints {
//    if (_postObject[TEXT_KEY] && _postObject[IMAGE_NAME_KEY]) {
//        self.imageMinusTextViewConstraint.priority = 800;
//        self.imagePlusTextViewConstraint.priority = 999;
//        self.textViewMinusImageViewConstraint.priority = 800;
//        self.textViewPlusImageViewConstraint.priority = 999;
//        
//    }
//    else if (_postObject[IMAGE_NAME_KEY]) {
//        self.imageMinusTextViewConstraint.priority = 999;
//        self.imagePlusTextViewConstraint.priority = 800;
//    }
//    else if (_postObject[TEXT_KEY]) {
//        self.textViewMinusImageViewConstraint.priority = 999;
//        self.textViewPlusImageViewConstraint.priority = 800;
//    }
//
//    [super updateConstraints];
//}
//
//
//- (void) layoutSubviews {
//    [super layoutSubviews];
//}



- (void) configureCellWith: (NSDictionary*) postObject {
    //Configurare gli elmenti già presenti
    self.postObject = postObject;

    //Check the presence of some kind of data
    if (postObject[TEXT_KEY] && postObject[IMAGE_NAME_KEY]) {
        self.imageMinusTextViewConstraint.priority = 800;
        self.imagePlusTextViewConstraint.priority = 999;
        self.textViewMinusImageViewConstraint.priority = 800;
        self.textViewPlusImageViewConstraint.priority = 999;
        self.postImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:postObject[IMAGE_NAME_KEY]];
        self.postTextView.text = postObject[TEXT_KEY];

    }
    else if (postObject[IMAGE_NAME_KEY]) {
        self.imageMinusTextViewConstraint.priority = 999;
        self.imagePlusTextViewConstraint.priority = 800;
        self.postImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:postObject[IMAGE_NAME_KEY]];
        self.postTextView.text = nil;
        [self.contentView bringSubviewToFront:self.postImageView];

    }
    else if (postObject[TEXT_KEY]) {
        self.textViewMinusImageViewConstraint.priority = 999;
        self.textViewPlusImageViewConstraint.priority = 800;

        self.postTextView.text = postObject[TEXT_KEY];
        self.postImageView.image = nil;
        [self.contentView bringSubviewToFront:self.postTextView];

    }

//    [self setNeedsLayout];
//    [self layoutIfNeeded];



}
```